# Update user meta on wp_login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, custom-fields

This must be a very simple issue but I'm struggling with it, all I'm trying to do with this function is update a custom field to 0 upon user login. I've tried a few variants. This issue is that the custom field does not update.

I imagine the issue is I'm not getting the current user info properly?

```
function expire_tier_discount( $user_id ) { 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'tier_progress_value', 0);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'expire_tier_discount');
```

another attempt:

```
function expire_tier_discount() { 
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'tier_progress_value', 0);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'expire_tier_discount');
```

another:

```
function expire_tier_discount( $user ) { 
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'tier_progress_value', 0);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'expire_tier_discount');
```

Comment: ah I edited the question to clarify the issue is that the field just doesn't update on login, as per your suggestion it's what I tried in the 3rd function I posted, no luck :/

Comment: Well the custom field is on the profile user page in the back end, so my testing has been logout, clear cache, login, go back to that page and see if the field has been set to 0 or is still at the random number value I set it to for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function expire_tier_discount( $user_login, $user ) { 
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'tier_progress_value', 0);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'expire_tier_discount', 10, 2);
```

You were not quite using the `wp_login` action correctly. The [wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) action passes in the user-login as the first parameter, and the actual user, a [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object, as the second argument -- you want the second argument. Also, you need to specify that you want 2 parameters passed in when setting up your action.

PS. Some of you may be wondering: Okay, but why didn't `$user = wp_get_current_user();` work? According to the [Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login), the `wp_login` action is the very last action triggered within the `wp_signon` function, and according to a note within the [user.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L0) code:

> wp_signon() doesn't handle setting the current user.

So, your action was being called before the current user had been set.

Comment: Eish. This is true.

Comment: Confirmed to work! I had tried including $user_login before, going off someone else's post, but they also suggested to include global $wpdb; & var_dump($user); which worked, but gave me a bunch of wp generated errors at the login screen.